# Assembly Location Changes in Runtime

Tags: c#, assemblies, custom-attributes, coded-ui-tests

I'm running coded ui automation and defined a method attribute called `[ExternalDataSource()]` to read a document (csv, xml...) and parse the data into some dictionaries. I'll copy it here so you can have a better insight:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class ExternalDataSource : System.Attribute
{
    public ExternalDataSource(string filename)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        string file = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(di.FullName), filename);

        try
        {
            code
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new UITestException("Cannot load data source document");
        }
    }
}
```

In it I try to access `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` to get a file that is copied to the TestResult/Out folder. I assigned this attribute to only one TestMethod() in the whole application and while debugging, I found out that the application enters the attribute's c'tor twice. Both times the Location is different. Once it's from the bin/Debug folder, the other time it's from the TestResults/Out folder. Two questions:

1. Why does the debugger enter that attribute twice if I call it only once in my application?
2. Why does the location of the same assembly change?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems nobody had an answer, but while debugging a run from the command line using `mstest.exe` with the vs2012 JIT Debugger i found out a strange thing:

When putting a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` in the class where this attribute is the jitter was called from **MSTest.exe** but when this breakpoint was in the `testmethod` decorated with this attribute, **QTAgent32.exe** was called. I had implemented a singleton class to handle my parameters, and while it was populated in ExternalDataSource in this attribute by MSTest, when entering QTAgent32 (the test) it was empty.

The solution that worked for me was just to initialize that Singleton with the data on `[TestInitialize()]`.

Hope this helps somebody.